# .htaccess non redirect subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have issue with my .htaccess .
I have one domain like medomain.com
I redirect all http, http://www, www, https://www to https://medomain.com with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://medomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

..but i don't want redirect & subdomains like demo.medomain.com

How i can fix it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a condition to restrict this to main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?medomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```